# Getting 400 Bad Request in cUrl - PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am running the following code and getting this error:

> Bad Request
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
>
> Additionally, a 400 Bad Request error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

```
    <?php
      $phone = "1236547895";
      $message = 'Dear '.$firstname.' '.$lastname.',

Your invoice (#'.$invoiceid.') is successfully paid on '.$datepaid.' at Hostomy. Thank you for choosing us.

Regards,
Hostomy
';
      $url = "https://www.example.com/file.php?phone=".$phone."&message=".$message."";
      $ch = curl_init();
      $timeout = 10;
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $data;
    ?>
```

Comment: Try defining $phone and $message.

Comment: added in question.

Comment: Have you got the open_ssl php5 extension installed? This could matter for HTTPS.

Comment: If i "echo $url" then it will show full $url very fine but not working with cURL.

Comment: If you copy/paste the `$url` directly in your browser, it works?

Answer (score 21):

Try [urlencode](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the message and the $phone vars :
`$url = "https://www.example.com/file.php?phone=".urlencode($phone)."&message=".urlencode($message)."";`

Comment: Phew. A life saver +1

Comment: Saved another hour.